# when login time click on remember set in cookies and when get from cookies and set into model bu value not set into password type textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
when login time click on remember set in cookies and when get from cookies and set into model bu value not set into password type textbox

HTML





       @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "login" }))
                    {
                        <form role="form" action="#">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { @type = "text", @name = "username", @placeholder = "Username", @required = "", @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "form-control", @id = "password", @placeholder = "Password", @required = "" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @type = "checkbox", @name = "remember", @value = "true", @class = "i-checks" })
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>
                        </form>
    }


    code(controller)

    set into cookies


         if (model.RememberMe)
                            {
                                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
                                var UserName = model.name;
                                var Password = model.Password;
                                cookie.Values.Add("user", UserName);
                                cookie.Values.Add("Password", Password);
                                //cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(6);
                                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                            }

Get time


    if (Request.Cookies["Login"] != null)
                {
                    var UserName =Request.Cookies["Login"].Values["user"];
                    var Password = Request.Cookies["Login"].Values["Password "];
                    model.UserName = UserName;
                    model.Password = Password;
                }
```

but load time  password not set into textbox and value not show when inspect broswer , value get from cookies bu not set into textbox andf when password text add @value=model.password set value but not well as security purpose

Comment: Why you want to set the password from server to client? And setting password in cookies is the biggest risk of compromising security? Can you share what is your requirements so that better solution can be suggested?

Comment: when user click on remember his password and user username for next time when login again so first set into cookies and get from cookies from server side

Comment: please suggest another method